# JSON data list passing from JSP page to controller

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

The following code i am using. What is the right way to get JSON list in Controller?

The following JSON form getting in Controller :

```
method One: {"sets":[{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"}]}

Method Two: [{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"}]
```

**JSP Code**

```
 var itemvalue;
     var items =[];
   function saveClearedDeatils(){

         $('#esiTable').find('tr').each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
                     {
                    var billitemId=row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
                    var amt =  row.find('input[type="text"]').val();
                     itemvalue={"billitemId":billitemId,"amount":amt};
                    items.push(itemvalue);
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(itemvalue));

                    /* items.push({
                        "item"   :   billitemId,
                        "amount" : amt
                    }); */
                }
            });
        var sets={"sets": items};
         $.post("dummyurl?sets="+JSON.stringify(sets),
                    function(data){
                alert("sldmhf");
            });
        /*  $.ajax({
                url: 'dummyurl',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(items),
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            }); */
     }
```

**IN Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dummyurl",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public  String dummy(@RequestParam("sets") String sets){


        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            List<Object>arrayJSON=mapper.readValue(sets, new TypeReference<List<ArrayJSON>>() {});
            System.out.println("fdkjvkfj");

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you get this data at controller. method One: {"sets":[{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"}]}

Method Two: [{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"250","amount":"1212"},{"billitemId":"245","amount":"1212"}]

Comment: Thanks for reply,
Ya i am getting it in string format.
but i am not how to handle in Controller.

Comment: You mean you want to convert JSON to String List or something else, sorry but i didn't understand your requirement.